# Identifier error in the string-type abstract variable

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am consuming an API that has the name "abstract" as the key. As soon as I create "private String abstract", Android Studio gives an error in this name, because it thinks I'm creating a method. How do I solve it?

```java
private String abstract;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbEWh.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, you can't use the word `abstract` as a field name, period. However, since you say "consuming an API", that most likely means something like a JSON REST API where you don't have the option of changing those names. In a case like this, you usually configure your mapper to use an alternate name. Additionally, while you can't name the *field* `abstract`, you can still name the *property* `abstract`.

Guessing that you're using Gson because this is Android, you want `@SerializedName`:

```java
@SerializedName("abstract")
private boolean abstractThing;
```

or

```java
private boolean _abstract;

// Gson should look for "abstract" since this is the property name
public boolean isAbstract() {
  return _abstract;
}

public void setAbstract(boolean value) {
  this._abstract = value;
}
```

Comment: I used SerializedName and managed to retrieve the value. Thank you very much.

Comment: @sambreves If this answer solved your problem, mark it by clicking the green checkmark on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

It's an error because `abstract` is a keyword. You can't use it for naming stuff, for the same reason you can't name something `class`, `public`, `int`, or `for`. It's not at all about 'it thinks I am creating a method'.

Just pick any other name. It is not possible to use a keyword as a method name in java-the-language.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract is a keyword in java along with 52 reserved keywords in java that have a special meaning and can not be used as an identifier.

Abstract is used to achieve Abstraction which is an essential part of Object-oriented programming.

```
Abstract Classes
A restricted class that cannot be used to create objects
ex- abstract class class-name{
    ...
    }

Abstract Method //used in cases of the Superclass method declaration
   ex- abstract map in java which is later implemented by HashMap, TreeMap
```

Abstract method can only be used in an abstract class, and it does not have a body. The body is provided by the subclass which inherits it.

You should just change the identifier name and that would solve your problem.